# Flask server is taking me to a 404 not found page

Tags: python, flask

When I follow the URL to my flask server which is `http://localhost:5000/`, I am taken to a page that says `Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

The following is my complete Flask server code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
# Allow CORS requests


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def do_classification():
    try:
        data = request.get_json()
        user_input = data['input']
        prediction = classify(user_input)
        print(f'Received input "{user_input}" from chat server')
        print(f'Classified input as: "{prediction}" from chat server')
        response = jsonify({'prediction': prediction})
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)})


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(port=5000)
```

I have run the command `python app.py` to run the server and the terminal output confirms that the server is up at  `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`. Not sure what else to do.

Comment: Should it be a GET request instead of POST?

Comment: Why did you write `methods=['POST']`?

Comment: You defined the `/` url to only accept POST requests.  But then you tried accessing it with a GET request...

Answer (score 1):

As it seems, your code has no problem, because I know the problem, I implemented it with GET and POST requests as follows:

GET Request:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/
Response:
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang=en>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

POST Request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"input": "text"}' http://localhost:5000/
Response:
{"prediction": "text"}
```

Probably the problem is something else, try to check it again with more precision and concentration

You can also make sure that Flask knows your paths with the following printout

```
print(app.url_map)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, I recommend that you learn about HTTP verbs, especially `GET` and `POST`. I assume when you say "I follow the URL to my flask server" you enter it in the browser. Your browser only does `GET`. In order to do `POST`, you will need to find an HTTP client such as curl or postman.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. I created a new route just to get to home, and kept the other route as a secondary 'post' root, and it still gives me 404, or method not found

Comment: @gothgamergal What do you do that causes the 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

trying to putt both the methods on and run.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```